# Upsource external links behaviour

Tags: upsource

I have two projects in our team upsource.
They are set up in the same way. And I set external link at both projects like this
[image: external links setup]

In both projects PyCharm detects these links and they acts like links that lead to our redmine (but I need to scroll to right if I want to see that links)
[image: detected links]

But, problem is, that only in one project Upsource creates a discussion where it writes some "explanation" with link
[image: explanation with link]

This explanation discussion very helpful, because I can see link in discussion list instead of scroll commits list to right.
How can I set same behaviour to all my projects?

Answer (score 0):

Upsource automatically adds the "explanation" comment, when a review is created from a commit with a long message. Normally, the whole commit message gets into a review title, but when it's too long, only the first line is taken. To avoid any confusion, the message is posted inside as an "explanation" discussion.